# Из .txt в словарь, python

Tags: python, словари

Есть .txt файл:

> Around the new position a circle, somewhat larger than in the former instance, was now described, and we again set to work with the spades. I was dreadfully weary, but, scarcely understanding what had occasioned the change in my thoughts, I felt no longer any great aversion from the labor imposed. I had become most unaccountably interested nay, even excited.

Каким образом его можно закинуть в словарь, чтобы ключами были слова, а значениями - частота их появления?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если надо игнорировать знаки препинания, то:

```py
import re

text = "Around the new position a circle, somewhat larger than in the former instance, was now described, and we again set to work with the spades. I was dreadfully weary, but, scarcely understanding what had occasioned the change in my thoughts, I felt no longer any great aversion from the labor imposed. I had become most unaccountably interested nay, even excited."

matches = re.findall(r"\b\w+\b", text) # Находим все слова
freqs = {word: matches.count(word) for word in set(matches)} # Составляем требуемый словарь

import json # Фишки для красивого вывода
print(json.dumps(freqs, indent=4))
```

Вывод:

```
{
    "larger": 1,
    "new": 1,
    "great": 1,
    "labor": 1,
    "longer": 1,
    "dreadfully": 1,
    "scarcely": 1,
    "set": 1,
    "spades": 1,
    "to": 1,
    "understanding": 1,
    "from": 1,
    "most": 1,
    "a": 1,
    "we": 1,
    "former": 1,
    "work": 1,
    "in": 2,
    "the": 5,
    "was": 2,
    "and": 1,
    "imposed": 1,
    "interested": 1,
    "no": 1,
    "felt": 1,
    "I": 3,
    "had": 2,
    "become": 1,
    "again": 1,
    "my": 1,
    "thoughts": 1,
    "now": 1,
    "Around": 1,
    "than": 1,
    "weary": 1,
    "described": 1,
    "circle": 1,
    "what": 1,
    "but": 1,
    "occasioned": 1,
    "position": 1,
    "somewhat": 1,
    "even": 1,
    "unaccountably": 1,
    "change": 1,
    "aversion": 1,
    "instance": 1,
    "with": 1,
    "any": 1,
    "excited": 1,
    "nay": 1
}
```

---

**P.S.** Стоит учесть, что слова вида `I'm` будут интерпретированы как 2 слова `["I", "m"]`.

Comment: `I'm` — это сокращение для `I am`, так что так даже правильнее (если закрыть глаза на `m`). Но тогда возникает проблема с притяжательными существительными, например, `Father’s pen`. Кажется, задача не так проста, как казалась мне на первый взгляд :)

Comment: @nomnoms12 Можно сделать регулярку `r"\b\w+(?:'\w)?\b"`. Думаю, этих "можно" можно дополнять очень много :)

Answer (score 4):

> ***UPD:*** Я не учёл, что следует игнорировать знаки препинания, поэтому данный код формально не удовлетворяет условиям задачи. Оставлю
>   его, как пример использования `Counter`, возможно, это кому-то будет
>   полезно.

---

Для таких целей Вы можете воспользоваться модулем `collections`, а именно — его классом `Counter`.

***Пример:***

```py
from collections import Counter


def main():
    with open('input.txt') as f:
        inp = f.read()

    d = dict(Counter(inp.split()))
    print(d)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
{'Around': 1, 'the': 5, 'new': 1, 'position': 1, 'a': 1, 'circle,': 1, 'somewhat': 1, 'larger': 1, 'than': 1, 'in': 2, 'former': 1, 'instance,': 1, 'was': 2, 'now': 1, 'described,': 1, 'and': 1, 'we': 1, 'again': 1, 'set': 1, 'to': 1, 'work': 1, 'with': 1, 'spades.': 1, 'I': 3, 'dreadfully': 1, 'weary,': 1, 'but,': 1, 'scarcely': 1, 'understanding': 1, 'what': 1, 'had': 2, 'occasioned': 1, 'change': 1, 'my': 1, 'thoughts,': 1, 'felt': 1, 'no': 1, 'longer': 1, 'any': 1, 'great': 1, 'aversion': 1, 'from': 1, 'labor': 1, 'imposed.': 1, 'become': 1, 'most': 1, 'unaccountably': 1, 'interested': 1, 'nay,': 1, 'even': 1, 'excited.': 1}
```